# Python If not exists css_selector take the other

Tags: python, css-selectors

I have the following code in my Jupyter notebook:

```
if driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.sc-52284603-0 > li:nth-child(3)').is_displayed():
    duracion = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".sc-52284603-0 > li:nth-child(3)").text
else:
    duracion = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".sc-52284603-0 > li:nth-child(2)").tex
```

But when I'm trying to run it I have this message: "Unable to locate element: .sc-52284603-0 > li:nth-child(3)"

I dont know how to get the other cssselector if the first one doesn't exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comma to create an OR in the CSS Selector and change your if else to use find_elements and end with size() is > 1. In your example, you could use:

```
.sc-52284603-0 li:nth-child(3), .sc-52284603-0 li:nth-child(2)
```

Which will find a size of 2 if both exist, otherwise will find size of 1